# Populating PHP inside Google Map script not working

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm sure this is a simple issue, but I just can't seem to find the answer. I am trying to simply put google map on a site using dynamic lat & long from php call.

When I have this code it works:

```
     <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869260, -122.254811);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: bryantPark,
    pov: {
      heading: 165,
      pitch: 0
    },
    zoom: 1
  };
  var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      panoramaOptions);
  myPano.setVisible(true);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>


    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

However, when I update it so that the LatLng is dynamic with php call like so:

```
<?php include("inc/conn.php"); ?>
```

....

```
 <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>

 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$row["field_Latitude"]?>, <?=$row["field_Longitude"]?>);
  var panoramaOptions = {
    position: bryantPark,
    pov: {
      heading: 165,
      pitch: 0
    },
    zoom: 1
  };
  var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      panoramaOptions);
  myPano.setVisible(true);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>


    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

When I view the source, I see that the lat & long are populating, but there is just a gray box where the street view should be.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the values that PHP returns for lat & long?

Comment: Hey Dr.Molle, The values are a Lat & Long from within my DB. So I know the call is good.

Comment: It must not be a matter of the call, it may be a issue with the values(streetView isn't available for each location in the world)

Comment: You may use the [StreetViewService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService) to check if there is a panorama available for a location

Comment: Interesting Dr.Molle! Using the link you provided I was able to now at least generate a map, but not streetview, or pin on map... One step closer! The street view is grayed out, but I know there is a streetview available, what is this telling me? Does it have to be a certain type of streetview in order to display?

Comment: it would really be helpful when you post the coordinates

Comment: 45.923931, -86.967087

Comment: so when you take a look at the browser->viewsource you see: `var bryantPark = new google.maps.LatLng(45.923931, -86.967087);` ?

Comment: Mine doesn't show "bryantPark" it shows: 
var berkeley = new google.maps.LatLng(45.923931, -86.967087);

Comment: then you must change `panoramaOptions.position` to `berkeley` http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7noptz5x/

Comment: 42.698776, -86.181015 grayed out... doesn't street view automatically go to the nearest street? or if logic is if no street view it's grayed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to show a map when streetView is not available(let's assume that streetview is not available when there is no panorama within a radius 50 meters), create a map and request the streetViewService to check if there is a panorama available for the given location.

When it does, set the position of the panorama and show it, otherwise do nothing.

```
function initialize() {
      //center of the map and position of the panorama (when available)
  var center          = new google.maps.LatLng(42.698776, -86.181015),

      //first initialize the map
      map             = new google.maps.Map(
                                            document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                            {
                                              zoom:21,
                                              center:center,
                                              mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                                            }
                                           ),
      svService       = new google.maps.StreetViewService(),
      panoramaOptions = {
                            pov: {
                                  heading: 165,
                                  pitch: 0
                              },
                            zoom: 1,
                            visible:true
                        };
        //test whether a panorama is available 
      svService.getPanoramaByLocation(center, 50, function(data,status){

          if(status==google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK){
              //panorama is available, show it
              var sv=map.getStreetView();
              sv.setPosition(center);
              sv.setOptions(panoramaOptions);
          }

      });
}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7noptz5x/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7noptz5x/)

Comment: Thanks Dr.Molle! This worked. However I just realized, the provider is giving me the wrong lat & longs! LOL of course after it's fixed I find another outside issue. Thanks this is still useful!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will use `<?php echo $row[...]; ?>` instead of `<?= $row[...] ?>` , just to be sure that code works also if you have [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) disabled.

Secondly, I'd put:

```
<?php
$row = array(
    'field_Latitude'  => 37.869260,
    'field_Longitude' => -122.254811
);
?>
```

instead of your `include` call and check the results to verify if I have something wrong in the included file.

In any case you should inspect the resulting HTML and check what are the real arguments passed to `LatLong` instead of the expected ones.

Comment: So I've updated to "echo $row..." that had the same result.

Short tags disable

When I added Array I was able to get streetview to load with dragging options and such with circle compass in top left, but there was no image, just gray box... However, almost produced results... 

I thought it could be CSS issue.